# In Linux, I am trying to write a user land app that can inspect some physical memory (for debug purposes)

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, pci, pci-e

I am trying to write a user land app that can inspect some physical memory (for debug purposes).

```
od -j <0xknown_good_physical_address> -N 256 /dev/mem
```

(w/ `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=n`)  crashes the OS.

functions `ioremap`, `phys_to_virt`, and `phys_to_page` don't exist in my `/usr/include` dir.  I researched and tried the `make headers_install` procedure but the functions still don't get into my usr/include dir.  AFAIK that means they're not available for user-land Apps. Does anyone know how to access physical memory from a user space app?  One more FYI, the physical address that I'm trying to read is a PCI BAR that I got from doing a `lspci -v` in the "memory at" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mmap() those addresses to get a virtual address that you can read and write depending on how you mmap.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote a kernel module utility that uses ioremap to access the physical address.  It works.  Do you mind if I don't follow-up on this?